# the placement of adverb "not" for infinitive verbs

Tags: grammar, adverbs

A recent article in [Politico](https://www.politico.com/news/2020/11/13/trump-week-of-silence-436493) had the following title

"Advisers almost universally encouraged Trump **to not say** much this week and urged him **not to take** questions on Friday after his first public remarks of the week"

Q1. Are all following alternative acceptable grammatically

- ... encouraged Trump **not to say** much this week and urged him **not to take** questions
- ... encouraged Trump **to not say** much this week and urged him **to not take** questions
- ... encouraged Trump **not to say** much this week and urged him **to not take** questions

Q2. Is the interpretation correct that the original title tried to put more emphasis on Trump "**not taking questions**", and less on Trump **not saying much** ? And the alternatives would merely shift the emphases according to the position of the adverb "**not**".

Comment: Related (or duplicates): https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/188469/not-to-or-to-not /// https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/112893/to-not-vs-not-to /// And this one on ELU: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23152/order-of-not-with-infinitive

Comment: Adding to Void's comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/73224/should-we-use-not-to-or-to-not?noredirect=1&lq=1